# Hystrix as a Service

Tags: routes, microservices, hystrix, api-gateway

Based on the examples found online, Hystrix Circuit Breaker is supposed to be used as a wrapper library on top of outbound service calls.
In essence, this means that one needs to adjust the code and inject dependencies for all the existing projects. This could prove to be highly expensive and risky.

So, an alternative option could possibly be having Hystrix as a dedicated service that will reside among apps that perform outbound service calls and apps that receive inbound calls.
That way, all existing apps would remain practilly intact and the Hystrix layer would be responsible for URI translation/routing **along with** circuit breaking logic.

Obviously, the downside is the maintenance of yet another application in your ecosystem which should always be up to date when new endpoints are being introduced between your apps. However, this is something I am willing to live with.

Has anyone implemented such a solution? Is that even feasible?
If not, would it make sense to utilize Hystrix as part of an API gateway?

*Disclaimer: I searched for similar questions but couldn't find anything similar.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to this but I'm leaning towards this being a bad idea. The layer of abstraction on the service level means that Hystrix itself will be a service dependency so you can't guarantee it is the downstream services that actually failed when Hystrix fails.

In that event, you will have false negatives, tripping the circuit when actuality it shouldn't be tripped. At the same time, say the service were to become alive again, the "Hysterix as a service" will have to somehow let the upstream service know that a response may be available. With all the said, it seems better if it was a library or a sidecar where it isn't affected by the physical network.

Comment: In the scenario I am examining, there is only one CB between upstream and downstream. So, if that CB goes down then there is nothing to provide false positives.  

I'm thinking that the solution of an API Gateway providing CB functionalities is our best option (assuming we need to handle hundreds of RESTful services residing all over the planet or being implemented/monitored/maintained by various vendors).  

Spring Cloud Gateway already has a Hystrix filter, while similar products alledgedly have built-in CB functionalities.

Comment: I think that circuit breaks to the first layer of the service which would work in that case but if you were an internal service making requests to an internal service that will be less useful, unless you put everything on the gateway which I don't agree that all services should be registered on the gateway.